# DateDiff isn't working in my access query

Tags: ms-access

[image]

My query in MS-access 2013:

`Delta : DateDiff("n", [C], [D])`

The error is french for "Expression syntax is invalid"

Comment: "n" is for seconds. You want to return difference in seconds? Expression works for me. Does function work in VBA?

Comment: "n" is for minutes, and yes I need it in minutes! I didnt tried in VBA. I'm not very familiar with. I really need it that query form...

Comment: Oops, minutes yes. Still, it worked for me. If it works in VBA, should work in query. If not, check for a MISSING library reference.

Comment: With French version, you probably need `;` in functions in query design. `DateDiff("n"; [C]; [D])`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the field names directly in the expression.

i.e date d reception and courriel de confirmation instead of D and C.